# How to estimate memory and disk needed for Spark Shuffle?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, shuffle

When using Spark-SQL, how to estimate memory and disk needed for Spark Shuffle?

SQL:

> select key, collect_set(value) from table_a group by key;

If table_a has N lines, K keys, each lines is b bytes, 
I can use C cores,is there a way to estimate memory and disk needed for spark shuffle?

spark version: 2.1.0, using sort-based shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

Without making any assumptions about key and value distribution the worst case scenario will be:

- `K - 1` keys with only single values.
- 1 key with `N - K + 1` unique values.

Assuming that properties of the hash function hold, and keys are distributed uniformly between cores this gives memory

```
(((N - K + 1) / C  + N - K + 1) * bytes) * serialization_efficiency
```

for the core with highest load where peak memory requirement should be proportional to (if data can be otherwise loaded from disk):

```
(N - K + 1) * bytes
```